# Extensions of $Z/p$ by $Z/p$ and uniqueness of cokernels

Tags: gr.group-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, ct.category-theory

I seem to run into something I cannot understand. Following Weibel (Homological Algebra), Ex. 3.4.1, p.76, it is claimed that if $p$ is prime, there are $p$ nonequivalent extensions of $Z/p$ by $Z/p$. He writes a short exact sequence in this way: $0\rightarrow Z/p\rightarrow^{p}Z/p^{2}\rightarrow^{i}Z/p\rightarrow 0$,  with $i=1, \ldots p-1$ and I understand that he means multiplication by $p$ (resp., $i$). Now, what it bothers me is that it seems that from this way of writing the extensions, that the monomorphism of this sequence, i.e., "multiplication by $p$" has $p-1$ different cokernels, that is, all the epimorphisms $Z/p^{2}\rightarrow^{i}Z/p$, i.e., "multiplication by $i$". This is clearly absurd since any homomorphism of abelian groups has only one cokernel. How should I understand/interpret correctly these sequences?

Comment: All the cokernels are isomorphic.  However, the maps themselves differ.  Think of it with a particular prime -- say $p=3$.  The two maps $\mathbb{Z}/9 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/3$ given by simple quotient and doubling, respectively, are indeed different, but the kernel of each is $3\mathbb{Z}/9$.

Comment: This is not appropriate for this site.


Comment: Steve D is right, so I deleted my answer.  AlexP, the display in Weibel is not wrong.  See Neil Epstein's comment above.